# C# Linq Query - Extracting multiple groups from a collection (nested groups?)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class called Person, with 2 properties Age and Name

I am trying to group the people into 3 different age groups.

I want my end result to be something like this:

```
YoungGroup (<20 y old):
    Person1Name, Age
    Person4Name, Age
    Person3Name, Age
AdultGroup (20> y <40 old):
    Person2Name, Age
    Person7Name, Age
    Person5Name, Age
SeniorGroup (40> y old):
    Person6Name, Age
    Person8Name, Age
    Person9Name, Age
```

I want to do it with group clause only (no join, if its even possible?)

This is what I have tried

```
var multiplegrps = from p in people
                   group p by p.Age into groups
                   let age = groups.Key
                   select new
                   {
                       YoungGroup = from p in groups
                                    where age <= 20
                                    group p by p.Age,
                       AdultGroup = from p in groups
                                    where age >= 21 && age <= 40
                                    group p by p.Age,
                      SeniorGroup = from p in groups
                                    where age >= 41
                                    group p by p.Age
                   };
```

Either it worked, or I dont actually know how to print it:

```
foreach (var item in multiplegrps)
{
    foreach (var i in item.YoungGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i.Key}");
    }
}
```

I do get the correct keys, but I have no access to the names, and I would have to write 3 internal foreachs for each of the groups

P.S. I want to do it with pure query only, no lambdas no new extension methods

P.S. I solved it and got the idea from @khoroshevj about the use of multiple ternary operators, it was as simple as:

```
        var peopleMultiGrouping = from p in people
                                  let ageSelection =
                                        p.Age < 20
                                            ? "Young" 
                                            : p.Age >= 20 && p.Age <= 40
                                                ? "Adult" 
                                                : "Senior"
                                  group p by ageSelection;

        foreach (var p in peopleMultiGrouping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{p.Key}");
            foreach (var i in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" {i.Age}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and got the idea from @khoroshevj about the use of multiple ternary operators, it was as simple as:

```
        var peopleMultiGrouping = from p in people
                                  let ageSelection =
                                        p.Age < 20
                                        ? "Young" 
                                        : p.Age >= 20 && p.Age <= 40
                                            ? "Adult" 
                                            : "Senior"
                                  group p by ageSelection;

        foreach (var p in peopleMultiGrouping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{p.Key}");
            foreach (var i in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" {i.Age}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var multiplegrps =
    from p in people
    let groupName = GetGroupName(p.Age)
    group p by groupName
    into groups
    group groups by groups.Key;

foreach (var group in multiplegrps)
{
    foreach (var member in group.SelectMany(i => i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}, {member.Age}, {member.Name}");
    }
}

private static string GetGroupName(int age)
{
    return age <= 20
        ? "YoungGroup"
        : age <= 40
            ? "AdultGroup"
            : "SeniorGroup";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like :

```
var multiplegrps = people.GroupBy(x=> x.age)
                         .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,
                                       x=>x.Select(y=>new {  
                                                 YoungGroup=y.where(z=>z.age<= 20), 
                                                 AdultGroup=y.Where(z=>z.age >=21 && a.age <= 40), 
                                                SeniorGroup=y.Where(z=> z.age >=41) 
                                                          });
```

This is just an idea, did not tried it...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does indeed work as you expected. The issue is the way you're printing the result.

In the second level loop, `i` is of type `IGrouping<int, Person>` which basically represents a collection of objects that have a common key.

It clearly has the `Key` property as you're accessing it, but it doesn't have a `Value`  property.

You can either perform another nested loop to iterate over the `IGrouping` and then you'll have access to the full `Person` properties, or if you want to only keep it at a two-level loop then you can flatten the `item.YoungGroup` with `SelectMany` into an `IEnumerable<Person>` and iterate over it like this:

```
foreach (var item in multiplegrps)
{
       foreach (var person in item.YoungGroup.SelectMany(x => x))
       {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {person.Name}, Age: {person.Age}");
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final grouped output you seem to be looking for is 3 discrete collections of person, i.e. Young, Adult and Senior persons.

To me, it would make sense to classify each person once, since from a performance point of view, you also won't want to run through all people 3 times (once per group) - the groups are mutually exclusive, and each person can be classified once into the age group:

```
var classifiedPersons = people
   .Select(p => new{
       Person = p, 
       AgeClassification = 
          p.age <= 20
            ? "Young"
            : p.age <= 40
                ? "Adult"
                : "Senior" 
    })
   .GroupBy(cp => cp.AgeClassification)
   .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(g => g.Person));
```

(You could use other classifications other than a string, such as enumeration here too)

You can now access the three groups via the "Young", "Adult" and "Senior" keys.

You can print out the groups generically like so:

```
foreach (var group in classifiedPersons)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group: {group.Key}:");
    foreach (var person in group.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  - {person.Name}:");
    }
}
```

Seemingly you wanted a single anonymous object containing all 3 groups, such as:

```
var allGroupsInOneObject = new {
   YoungPeople = classifiedPersons["Young"],
   AdultPeople = classifiedPersons["Adult"],
   SeniorPeople = classifiedPersons["Senior"]
};
```

One Caveat - before accessing the groups via the Dictionary Key, you might just need to ensure that there are any persons present in the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
foreach (var item in multiplegrps)
            {
                foreach (var yItem in item.YoungGroup)
                {
                    if (item.YoungGroup.Count() > 0 && yItem.ElementAt(0) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Young : " + yItem.ElementAt(0).Name);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var aItem in item.AdultGroup)
                {
                    if (item.AdultGroup.Count() > 0 &&aItem.ElementAt(0) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Adult : " + aItem.ElementAt(0).Name);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var sItem in item.SeniorGroup)
                {
                    if (item.SeniorGroup.Count() > 0 &&sItem.ElementAt(0) != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Senior : " + sItem.ElementAt(0).Name);
                        }
                }
            }
```